# Is it possible to get the latest set of files from Mercurial without creating a local repository?

Tags: mercurial, continuous-integration

I am working on a system that performs continuous integration and I am looking for a method I can use to get the most recent changeset from a Mercurial repository without creating a repository locally.

I have considered using `clone` but this method will only work if you have set a working directory locally (since this will be occurring on a build server, I would prefer not to do this because of inclusion of the `.hg` file and the diffs - all I want is essentially an export of the files from the tip revision and nothing more.)

This request may not even be possible, and it's very likely that I just do not understand DVCS very well. However, if I cannot do what I want to do, is there a workaround?

Comment: Why not clone and then delete the .hg directory?

Comment: @hwiechers - I'll probably have to do that, but I wanted to avoid pulling the entire history of changes along with the files I actually need

Comment: rasch If you just keep the repository around, it only needs to pull the changes, right? Will be much faster too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible using 'hg archive' depending how your remote repository is set up.

If it's available over HTTP using `hgweb.cgi` or `hg serve` you can hit the archive link programmatically to get the files you want.  Example:

```
wget https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/archive/tip.zip --output-document=- | unzip -
```

or it's available over ssh:

```
ssh you@there.com hg archive --type=zip - | unzip -
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$ hg clone http://your_repo
$ hg archive ../export/
$ rm -rf *
$ cd ..
$ cd export
```

From Mercurial's help files:

```
$ hg help archive
```

> hg archive [OPTION]... DEST
>
> create an unversioned archive of a
>   repository revision

Comment: When I do this, I get a "repository is not local" error... which seems to happen with every command, is there a way around this?

Comment: thanks for the update, unfortunately if I clone the repo before using archive then I've still grabbed the entire history... but there seems to be no way around doing this at this point so I'll have some work ahead of me

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
http://merc/raw-file
```

to retrieve a list of files in the repository or

```
http://merc/raw-file/filename
```

to get a specific file.